# How to find --name of kubernetes cluster in Azure portal?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

anyone knows how to find the name of a kubernetes cluster in azure portal? I did not create the cluster but I'm trying to connect to it and I don't know and can't find what to put in the --name tag

Comment: If you want to know the name of the cluster , contexts and user info you can use `kubectl config view`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the name of the kubernetes cluster is the name of the resource you see in the portal. As simple as that.

Just find the cluster in question and look how its called.

Comment: the one with type container service? is it the cluster resource?

Comment: How can we login to a AKS kluster created , by using service account?
the infra team asked us to create a cluster role binding  by executing the command,...
Could you please explain the step by steps as i am new to both Azure and Kubernetes

Comment: why'd you post a comment and not a question, post a question and link it

Answer (score 0):

The [az aks list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks#az-aks-list) command can list all Kubernetes clusters in given resource group. You can use the command to query names of your clusters:

```
>  az aks list --resource-group MyAKSRG --query "[].name"
[
  "MyCluster1",
  "MyCluster2",
]
```